# How to append a custom string at the end of the file?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to append a custom string at the end of the file.

For example using `:read` command this works:

```
:$r !echo my string
```

however is there any more portable way of doing that (without executing external program)?

I've tried:

```
:$r "my string"
```

but it's just duplicating content of my file (the same as: `:$r %`).

How to I specify literal string in this context?

Comment: `:call append('$', 'my string')` - not using a replace command though.  And by the way, `:r` is `read`, rather than replace.

Comment: @SatoKatsura You're right, I've corrected the title. I think I got confused by: `:help r`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `:put`:

```
:$put='my string'
```

See `:help :put`.

Answer (score 0):

I know 7 years too late and no one will probably read this... And I like @romainl [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5149/43725) more, but this is possible too:

`:r !echo $(cat %) my string`